# Perl remove characters with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a bit confused using regex in perl. I am trying to scrape a webpage, and it seems to yield strings like this: `Referred for adjudication-Orders issued.G.O.(Rt)No.826/2015/LBR\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0}\x{a0} Dated`

I tried using the following:

```
$file =~ s/\\x\{a0\}//g;
```

but it doesn't strip the characters. How do I remove the character `\x{a0}` with regex in perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I remove the character \x{a0} with regex in perl?

`s/\xa0//g` or `s/\x{a0}//g`.

Demonstration:

```
perl -wle 'print qq(a\x{a0}b) =~ s/\x{a0}//gr'
```

Because in double-quoted strings `\xHH` is an escape referring to an ASCII code-point HH where H is any hexadecimal digit and `\x{HHHH}` refers to a Unicode codepoint HHHH.

If you have a literal backslash, letter `x`, etc. in your string, `s/\\x\{a0\}//g` will work, but you are probably printing it with something which is escaping that string.

Demonstration (single-quoted string does not interpolate):

```
perl -wle 'print q(a\x{a0}b) =~ s/\\x\{a0\}//gr'
```